# Filtragem de produtos não funciona em navegadores de dispositivos moveis

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho um site que contém alguns produtos com categoria.
Escrevi um código que checa se as caixas de seleção de categoria estão selecionadas e mostra apenas os itens correspondente a ela.

O código funciona no Google Chrome do computador, mas não funciona nos navegadores de celular.

Alterei pra ele pintar de azul, mas no código original eu uso *Display: block ou none;*

Exemplo do meu código:

```js
function filtrar()
{
var checks = document.getElementsByClassName("ContainerCaim");

var qtdCategoria = document.getElementById("produtos").getElementsByClassName("categoria").length;

var contProduto = document.getElementById("produtos").getElementsByClassName("categoria").length;

for(var x = 0; x < contProduto; x++)
{
  document.getElementById("produtos").getElementsByClassName("categoria")[x].style.color = "black";
}


for(var i = 0;i < checks.length;i++)
  {
  if(checks[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked)
    {
      
      for(var ii = 0;ii< qtdCategoria; ii++){
      if(document.getElementById("produtos").getElementsByClassName("categoria")[ii].innerText == checks[i].innerText)
      {
          document.getElementById("produtos").getElementsByClassName("categoria")[ii].style.display = "blue";
      }

    }
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="FiltroCaimentos" style="display: inline-block;margin-top: 50px;">

<label  class="containerCaim">Skinny
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="containerCaim">Straight
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="containerCaim">Slim
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<button onclick="filtrar()">Filtar</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="produtos">

  <div class="categoria">Skinny</div>

  <div class="categoria">Straight</div>

  <div class="categoria">Slim</div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Na hora que eu estava criando a pergunta, ao testar os códigos de exemplo acabei resolvendo meu problema.

Acontece que eu estava usando *innerText* sem tratamento (para remover espaços, por exemplo). No navegador do computador, parece que os nomes comparados não vinham com espaço, e no celular tinha.

Adicionei um *.replace(/\s+/g, '')* nas minhas comparações no *innerText* e funcionou em ambos navegadores.